# PHP connecting to AWS EC2 error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I connect to amazon ec2 through php. However, it says unknown MySQL server host. Thanks in advance!

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'http://ec2-54-86-44-206.compute-1.amazonaws.com');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'PW');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'DB');

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
```

Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'http://ec2-54-86-44-206.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (3) in /home/httpd/html/creasant.net/project15.creasant.net/peter/include/test.php

Comment: try removing http://

Comment: I'd change the server name to the IP address of the server...If it is static, will cut out the mapping of the name to the IP.

Comment: `ec2-54-86-44-206.compute-1.amazonaws.com` or its IP. Why don't you make an answer @Cythral

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't connect over HTTP, so you will want to remove http:// from the DB_SERVER constant:

```
define("DB_SERVER", "ec2-54-86-44-206.compute-1.amazonaws.com");
```

Alternatively, you could connect using the IP address instead:

```
define("DB_SERVER", "54.86.44.206");
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use http://ec2-54-86-44-206.compute-1.amazonaws.com use **localhost** as DB is local to you

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'PW');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'DB');

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: Hi everyone, I am now encountering this error: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'x.x.x.x' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in ... am I setting wrongly in the security group?

HTTP TCP 80 0.0.0.0/0
SSH TCP 22 0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule TCP 3306 0.0.0.0/0